# `react-native-render-html` default WebView props (`originWhitelist `)

Tags: react-native, react-native-render-html

I am using `react-native-render-html` in my `react-native` application and successfully rendering HTML:

```
import RenderHtml from 'react-native-render-html'
import WebView from 'react-native-webview'

export const MyComponent = (props: {html: string, width: number}) => (
    <RenderHtml
        source={{html: props.html}}
        contentWidth={props.width}
        WebView={WebView}
     />
)
```

How can I specify the `originWhitelist` props for the `WebView` component (or any other `WebView` props for that matter)?

I intend to use `originWhitelist` to control the list of origins from which I can load content in an attempt to reduce the surface area for an attacker who could control the HTML content (I am using the `'@native-html/iframe-plugin'` to load `iframes`. Note that I have not included that code for brevity).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`defaultWebViewProps`](https://meliorence.github.io/react-native-render-html/api/renderhtmlprops#defaultwebviewprops) for that purpose:

```js
import RenderHtml from 'react-native-render-html'
import WebView from 'react-native-webview'

const webViewProps = {
  originWhitelist: "*"
};

export const MyComponent = (props: {html: string, width: number}) => (
    <RenderHtml
        source={{html: props.html}}
        contentWidth={props.width}
        WebView={WebView}
        defaultWebViewProps={webViewProps}
     />
)
```